old State value in function in React
I have a problem with state in react. I'm create state with base empty value. Then i'm using function which set state value and then take new state value (as i thought) into next function. But my state has old value. When i call console.log inside of my function with state i have new value.
I know that useState is async function, but it's cant't help me). For creation state i use hook.
const { formData, setFormData } = useSetFormData({
    userSearchRequest: "",
    checkedUsers: [],
  });

  const handlUpdateCheckedUser = (userData, isChecked) => {
    if (formData.checkedUsers && formData.checkedUsers.length > 0) {
      if (!isChecked) {
        setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
          ...formData,
          checkedUsers: prevFormData.checkedUsers.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === userData.id) {
              return {
                ...item,
                readOnlyAccess: false,
                readAndEditAccess: false,
              };
            }
            return item;
          }),
        }));
        const changedRecordIndex = formData.checkedUsers.findIndex((item) => item.id === userData.id)
        const updatedUserData = formData.checkedUsers[changedRecordIndex];
        isAccessToRecord(updatedUserData);
        console.log(updatedUserData);
      }

    }
  };

  console.log(formData);

  useEffect(() => {}, [formData])

In the function "handlUpdateCheckedUser" i'm update state "checkedUsers" and in the same function i'm throw new state into function "isAccessToRecord" (but there is old state).
Console.log outside shows me ne value. I have no idea how to solve that.

If you want to call isAccessToRecord after setFormData is done, you should use an useEffect with a dependancy array on the formData:
useEffect(() => {
    const changedRecordIndex = formData.checkedUsers.findIndex((item) => item.id === userData.id)
    const updatedUserData = formData.checkedUsers[changedRecordIndex];
    isAccessToRecord(updatedUserData);
}, [formData])


But i need recordId which stay in my function and i can't take this value frome here

change your function to this.
const handlUpdateCheckedUser = (userData, isChecked) => {
  if (formData.checkedUsers && formData.checkedUsers.length > 0) {
    if (!isChecked) {
      setFormData((prevFormData) => {
        const temp = {
          ...formData,
          checkedUsers: prevFormData.checkedUsers.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === userData.id) {
              return {
                ...item,
                readOnlyAccess: false,
                readAndEditAccess: false,
              };
            }
            return item;
          }),
        }
        const changedRecordIndex = temp.checkedUsers.findIndex(
          (item) => item.id === userData.id
        );
        const updatedUserData = temp.checkedUsers[changedRecordIndex];
        isAccessToRecord(updatedUserData);
        return temp 
      });
    }
  }
};

